# Choosing rangefinder for obstacle-avoiding

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am looking to buy a range finder module for an obstacle avoidance robot. 
Currently, two good options based on available libraries and compatibility with Arduino and rPI are HC-SR04 and parallax ping.

In terms of form factor these seem the same. The only difference I can tell is 4 pins vs 3 pins. Also the price, with parallax being more than x4 the price. As I would rather not buy something cheaper which will need replacing, is anyone aware of further differences, that will make the parallax a better option?

both need 5V
both have max range of 3-4m
Sensor angle HC- 15 degrees, parallax cant find..

Comment: They are the same. parallax wants /$ for a resistor; http://letsmakerobots.com/node/36885

Comment: @Spiked3 they can both be made to communicate with 3 pins, but do they have the same detection characteristics? It doesn't say they are actually the same hardware/mics.

Comment: Odds are pretty good they are real close. I've only used the sr04 with 4 pins (too lazy to mod) and it was ok. cant say if the parallax is better or not. For 4 times the price you'd expect it to be, but so far in robotics, price seldom reflect performance in my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Odds are pretty good they are real close. I've only used the sr04 with
>   4 pins (too lazy to mod) and it was ok. cant say if the parallax is
>   better or not. For 4 times the price you'd expect it to be, but so far
>   in robotics, price seldom reflect performance in my experience. – 
>   Spiked3

I've also used the SR (with 4 pins) and it worked great. <2$ on eBay